# Ruby on Rails: redirect unauthenticated user to root instead of the sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Rails 4 and Devise 3.

I am using the following in the routes file to prevent access to a page from non authenticated users (not signed in):

```
authenticate :user do
   #page to protect 
end
```

This redirects me to the user/sign_in page, but I want the user to be redirected to the root. So, I added the following as well to the routes page:

```
get 'user/sign_in' => redirect('/')
```

But this will mess up what I did in the sessions_controllers:

```
def new
    return render :json => {:success => false, :type => "signinn", :errors => ["You have to confirm your email address before continuing."]}
end
```

This will stop showing. So, I would like another solution that redirects users to the root directly, instead of having to use `authenticate :user` and then `get 'user/sign_in' => redirect('/')`.

The following may not have anything to do with redirecting the user to the root, but I would like to explain more about why I am overwriting the new method in the sessions_controller. I moved the sign_in and sign_up views to the root page (home page). In this case, I also needed to hack the error messages so that they appear in the home page, instead of redirecting the user to user/sign_in to show the errors. I used ajax for that.

### Update

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
if user_authenticated? 
  #show the protected page
else  
  # redirect the user to the ROOT
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't understand your question, anyway you can do something like this:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def route(scope)
      #return super unless [:worker, :employer, :user].include?(scope) #make it specific to a scope
       new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
    end

    # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
    def respond
      if http_auth?
        http_auth
      else
        redirect
      end
    end
  end
```

And in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

This was taken from the wiki of devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Comment: This will still redirect the user to user/sign_in thought, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can set your `devise` scope to look something like this.

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'pages#dashboard', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'session#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

EDIT (Based on the new info):

If you have something like this in your `routes.rb`

```
root to: 'visitors#index`
```

then you can have something like this in your `visitors_controller.rb`

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user
      redirect_to some_authenticated_path
    else
      # business logic here
    end
  end
end
```

You will still want to handle the propper authorization requirements and authentication requirements in the `some_authenticated_path` controller and action.

Comment: :( Not quiet what I need. This will use the session#new, which I prefer to stay away from. Could you please check the update I added to my question? Hopefully that explains what I need more. Thank you.

Comment: In your root action, you could put if current_user redirect, else the normal actions.